# JAVA tabs design

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a GUI window in Java with 4 tabs at the top **Home**, **Booking**, **Guest**, **Room**. However, the problem is that I'm not sure how to implement buttons in specific tab.

More specific, I made a class called GuestTab and I made 1 button and 1 textfield, but I don't know how can I convey those informations to a Guest tab.

So, if I wasn't so clear, when I click on Guest tab I want to have buttons and text fields that I made in GuestTab class.

I'll put the code of "SEP" class, where I have my GUI main design and "GuestTab" class where I'm adding stuff for Guest tab.

SEP.java:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SEP extends JFrame
{

  private GuestTab GuestTab;
  private JTabbedPane tPane;
  private MyButtonListener buttonListener;
  private MyTabListener tabListener;
  private JMenuBar menuBar;
  private JMenu fileMenu;
  private JMenuItem exitMenuItem;

  public SEP()
  {
    super("Deer Alley Hotel");

    buttonListener = new MyButtonListener();
    tabListener = new MyTabListener();

    exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(buttonListener);

    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    tPane = new JTabbedPane();

    tPane.addTab("                Home             ", new JPanel(
         new FlowLayout()));
    tPane.addTab("               Booking           ", new JPanel(
        new FlowLayout()));
    tPane.addTab("              Guest           ", GuestTab);
    tPane.addTab("              Room        ", new JPanel(new FlowLayout()));
    tPane.addChangeListener(tabListener);

    add(tPane);

    setSize(575, 452);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  }

  private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if (e.getSource() == exitMenuItem)
      {
        int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
              "Do you really want to exit the program?", "Exit",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public class MyTabListener implements ChangeListener
  {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

GuestTab.java:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuestTab extends JPanel
{
  private JButton button1;
  private JButton button2;
  private JButton button3;
  private JButton button4;

  private JPanel panel1;
  private JPanel panel2;

  private JTextField text;

  public GuestTab() 
  {
    panel1 = new JPanel();

    button1 = new JButton("Edit Note");
    button2 = new JButton("Check out");
    button3 = new JButton("Edit Form");
    button4 = new JButton("Search");

    text = new JTextField(15);

    add(panel1);
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 300));
    panel1.add(button4);
    panel1.add(text);
    setVisible(true);
  }        

 }
```

Comment: you reallllly need to fix your formatting haha

Comment: Not sure what your intent is...it would really help you AND those trying to answer your question if you formatted your code in such a way that made it readable. (ex: separate custom JPanel into separate .class eetc

Comment: Well, it's not like this in my Eclipse :) I used ctrl+shift+f, but here it is )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining your GuestTab properly.

In this line:

```
tPane.addTab("Guest", guestTab);
```

Change it to:

```
tPane.addTab("Guest", new GuestTab());
```

Or you can initialize the JPanel. You never actually do this you just say 
there is a guest tab but you never do anything with it so you can also do:

```
private GuestTab guestTab;
```

and then later:

```
guestTab = new GuestTab();
```

Side note, never use the same case for the variable definition and class call. Make sure you are using proper camel case.

Comment: No worries :) make sure to keep track of what you are doing

Comment: I'm newbie, I get lost all the time hehe :) One day it might go smoothly :) Cheers and ty

Comment: @Seinfeld you should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I did it now, didn't know that =)